# Component interaction shared variable through all app Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have **app.component.ts**, **header.component.ts**, **users.component.ts** and **shared.service.ts** with one variable "**options**".

In **app.component.html** I have something like that:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Where **app-heade**r - related to **header.component.ts**, **router-outlet** - related to **users.component.ts**

In **app.component.ts** in **ngOnInit()** I do ajax-request to get **"options"** and set:

```
sharedService.options = "result of ajax"
```

Then I want to use **sharedService.options** variable in **ngOnInit()** method of *header* and *users* components. But sometimes I have error that `sharedService.options.property is undefined`.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: You should use an observable https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 0):

You use an observable in your service & in ngOnInit,
You subscribe to that service.
That's the usual pattern.

Something like this .

in service.ts

```
getAll():Observable<Object[]>{     
      return this.http.get(this.newsURL)
                .map(res=>res.json())
                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

And in ngOnInit
You make an object of service in constructor &

```
this.myObject.getAll.subscribe(
 //logic goes here what u want to do for service return type.
)
```